# how to resolve issue with uploading files to s3 from amazon emr cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I see this error message every time my job is processing.

```
Error: com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils.copy(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/io/OutputStream;)J
```

My job has uploaded a particular file to s3 even though the job actually creates 5 files in total simultaneously and all the files are supposed to be uploaded to s3. Only one of those files is getting partially/fully uploaded to s3. I am not sure whether this is a conflict with the dependency tree of my workflow scheduler or something to do with the code I am using. I can see that there are 3 dependencies that are resolved for the:

```
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>.
```

One is 1.9.26 and two other with lower version numbers.

Could this be one reason for the above issue? If yes how do I resolve it? If no, any other suggestions as to what I should be trying to do?

The jars that have to be used all reside on s3. When I run the same workflow by launching a job manually and not through the scheduler, I see that the process runs fine on a cluster meant for manual runs. I am currently in no mans land trying to figure this out. Please help!

Comment: Can you post how you are submitting the application including arguments?

Comment: It is a json which i give to my application. Another thing is that now none of the files are getting uploaded to s3.